# Keyboard appears scaled up - iPhone 6

Tags: ios, iphone, cocoa-touch, uikeyboard

I am using standard iOS API to get the keyboard for a `UISearchBar` or `UITextField` but this looks different (in font size of the keyboard letters) than in standard iOS app.

Thinking keyboard is scaled up due to missing launch images meant for iPhone 6/6P, I got them added too (Default-667h@2x.png & Default-736h@3x.png) but see no difference.

Font size in Settings app is also set to normal.

What could be causing this scaled up view of my keyboard.

[image]

Comment: How about the status bar? Is it scaled up when your app is running and back to normal when switching to another app?

Comment: Yes, apparently, status bar has similar behavior. It's scaled up when I run my app and is back to normal when I go to background.

Comment: You don't have the proper launch images. That's it. It would be much simpler if you use a launch screen storyboard instead of messing with launch images.

Comment: You were right @rmaddy. With right launch images it got sorted out. Do you mind putting your suggestion in answer so I accept it and may be someone else can be benefitted too.